# (PureJS/CSS) Fade between hidden div tab

Tags: javascript, css

As the title reads, I'm trying to make my hidden div fades between tab.

I'm not sure if what i'm asking is logical, so to clarify:

When switching between tabs (hidden div) the page will fade between them, not just  from `0 to 1` but `0 to 1 to 0` from page to page. Does that make sense?

My JS looks something like this:

```
function btns(evt, btnName) {
  var i, containerMain, tablinks;
  containerMain = document.getElementsByClassName("containerMain");
  for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
    containerMain[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(btnName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
    containerMain[i].scrollLeft = 0;
    containerMain[i].scrollTop = 0;
  }
}
```

While my CSS looks something like this:

```
.containerMain {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 285px;
  width: 440px;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 0px 8px 0 2px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

[Here's an example of the desired result,](https://jsfiddle.net/100hyun/nqh3ro67/) only this fiddle uses jQuery

[Here's my fiddle,](https://jsfiddle.net/100hyun/f04q18xL/) which uses pure JS

P/S: I'm still very unfamiliar with JavaScript, or any script language tbh.

Comment: I advise you to look into the fiddles I provide beforehand so you can grasp the idea :)

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I'm sorry but I don't think the HTML code has to do with this, unless you clarify the need for that? Or you could visit the fiddle I've provided to see the HTML

Comment: I would recommend keeping all of your code in a stack snippet on this page. Links to a fiddle could die. And having HTML with your JS and CSS provides context for your programming and styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick lies in a combination of *states*, and *transitions*. The states are in this case CSS classes. In CSS you can define if you show or hide an element. With adding and removing classes you can toggle and / or select these states.

Create these states like the example in CSS below. This also keeps your CSS and HTML split. This is a good practice in building websites, but can also be a personal preference.

Instead of an animation use the `transition` property. This will gradually change the value that is changed. So in this case the `opacity` will change from `0` to `1` and from `1` to `0` in the given duration. The `visibility` prop does not animate, but does wait for the opacity to finish before changing its own value.

```
.containerMain {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 285px;
  width: 440px;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 0px 8px 0 2px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

/** 
 * Hidden state.
 * Hide element by default. 
 */
.containerMain {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition-property: opacity, visibility;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

/** 
 * Active state.
 * Show element on active class. 
 */
.containerMain.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

In JavaScript use [`Element.classList.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) and [`Element.classList.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) to manipulate the classes on the elements. They make it a lot easier to add or remove a certain class.

In the snippet below the loops will first remove all `active` classes from your panels, which will fade them out, and then add the `active` class to the newly selected element which will fade it in.

```
function btns(evt, btnName) {
  var i, containerMain, tablinks; 
  containerMain = document.getElementsByClassName("containerMain");
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
    containerMain[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  document.getElementById(btnName).classList.add('active');
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  for (i = 0; i < containerMain.length; i++) {
    containerMain[i].scrollLeft = 0;
    containerMain[i].scrollTop = 0;
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly like how I wanted, although I had some hard time figuring out why my `containerMain` doesn't stays in one place (maybe that's the reason why you need to see the HTML), and that is because my `position` was `relative` so I replaced it to `absolute` and it stays in one place. Good job!

Comment: Yes, thats the reason I asked for it. Glad you figured the `absolute` puzzle out. Have you ever tried out CSS Grid? In my opinion your layout is perfect for it and might save a lot of hassle with positioning elements.

Comment: I haven't heard of that tbh.. And you're right! ahahah wished I known about that sooner..